# Updating custom DialogPreference's title in a SettingsFragment

Tags: android

I have a `PreferenceActivity` that shows several custom classes based on `DialogPreference`.  They appear from the `PreferenceActivity` as a `TextView` that, when clicked, displays a dialog to allow the user to set a value.  I'd like the view shown in the `PreferenceActivity` to include the setting's title (i.e. "Volume"), plus its value ("Loud").  That's not hard to do with `setTitle()` and `getTitle()` from `Preference`.  That works fine for initially viewing the `PreferenceActivity`, but once I make a change and go back to the `PreferenceActivity` from my custom dialog, the title doesn't update.  I've tried updating it when the value changes, and when the dialog is dismissed, but it doesn't update until the setting gets clicked again (an instant before it shows that dialog again).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your custom view manually from the PreferenceActivity. For example for a ListDialog you can do:

```
 ListPreference myList = (ListPreference) findPreference("listPref");
 myList.setSummary(your_string);
```

For editText:

```
EditTextPreference myEditTextPref = (EditTextPreference)findPreference("myEditText");
```

Use findPreference() method and update your view with its methods setSummary(), setTile() etc.

Comment: I call `setTitle()` from within the custom `DialogPreference` when it detects that it has been edited, but the change isn't visible until the user clicks on the control in the `PreferenceActivity`'s `ListView`